# iOS Charts display yAxis values multiple of X

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I have a line chart. How can I make the yAxis values to be multiple of 100 or 1000 or X?

So the chart displays `£0`, `£400`, `£800`, `£1000` instead of what's on the screenshot.

I don't want to use the value formatter `stringForValue` and round the `398` to `400` as it's not correct. I want the lines to be on the `400`, `800` etc.

Also when the chart has `leftAxis.axisMinimum` not equal `0` (eg. -100) how can I force the chart to display the first (lowest) line at `0` not at actual axisMinimum?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make min and max axis to divisible by 400 and set the granularity and label count

```
let min: Int = (minY / 400) * 400 - 400 // make min divisible by 400
    let max: Int = (maxY / 400) * 400 + 400 // make max divisible by 400
    let count: Int = (max / 400) + (0 - min / 400) + 1 // + 1 for 0 label
    chart.leftAxis.granularity = 400
    chart.leftAxis.setLabelCount(count, force: true)
    chart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = Double(min)
    chart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = Double(max)
```

and just add first entry with 0 y value

```
ChartDataEntry(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Comment: I tried to set the granularity - it doesn't change anything `leftAxis.granularityEnabled == true` and `leftAxis.granularity = 400` (or any other value). Regarding filtering entries - it's not correct, as they should appear below the zero line if they have negative x.

Comment: you said you want force the chart to display the first (lowest) line at 0 not at actual axisMinimum. maybe I miss interpreting what you want to achieve